# Application creating / deleting local xml files when installed

Tags: c#, .net, xml, file, local

I have an application that needs to create, read and delete 2 xml files. These files are stored in the same directory as the application file. When I run this application in debug it works fine. but as soon as you create an installer for this and run the installed program it failed to create the files. Is there any way I can set the application permission to the folder it has been installed to?

Any help would be great.

Thank you

Here is the code im using:

```
   if (File.Exists("ApplicationData.xml") == true)
                {
                    File.SetAttributes("ApplicationData.xml", FileAttributes.Normal);
                    File.Delete("ApplicationData.xml");
                }

                doc.Save("ApplicationData.xml");
```

This is throwing a System.UnauthorizedAccessException

Comment: Did you get an exception or any error message?

Comment: Did you try to run as an administrator?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than start changing directory permissions, how about putting the files into the temporary directory? You can get the directory from `Path.GetTempPath()`.

Comment: Or use the AppData folder `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)`

Comment: @coshmos - yep, that'd do, too. I suggested the temp folder as it sounds like the files are transient.

Comment: Definitely better to target folders you know you will have access too; Program Files will be locked down if not running as an Admin user (fell foul to that one before...) and it sucks to have to tell people "you need to install as administrator" Upvoted - should be accepted answer :).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to create a "tmp" folder from your application, and then create your xml files inside . This will guarantee you that have permission on the folders, as you have created them in the privilege scope of the application.

```
  string folderName = @"Folder";
  string pathString = System.IO.Path.Combine(folderName, "SubFolder");
  System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(pathString);
```

Here i've tested it out for you:
http://pastebin.com/cAmFQvee

This works fine